# jQuery Delegate callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems with the handler callback using `.delegate()` in jQuery.  This setup uses 2 files- on where $B is created, and the other a simple $(doc).ready file.

I have an SVG file with a bunch (50+) of `<g>` tags I need to track when I click, rollover, rollout, etc. Instead of attaching the functions to the `<g>` nodes, delegate looked like a cleaner option.

However, I'm running into an issue which I think is my relative lack of knowledge on JavaScript.

Here's the setup for my main ready() file:

```
$C.Events.onStation({
    click : function(e){
        console.log(e)
            return false;
    },
    mouseenter : function(e){
        return false;
    },
    mouseleave : function(e){
        return false;
    }
})
```

That works fine.  Everything's passed through, etc. Inside my $B.Events Object:

```
Events : new function(){
    var _station = function(obj){
        // delegate the events to the primary SVG node
        for(var type in obj){
            $(City.Map.node).delegate('g', type, function(){
            obj[type]()
        })
    }
    return {
        onStation : _station
    }
    // others taken out for relevance
}()
```

Now, with this, if I just pass in `obj[type]` instead of wrapping it in another function, it works fine.  Only problem with that is I need to do some pre-work with the function being passed in (i.e. messing with the event data object) as well as moving all the `return false`'s into the delegation code and not muck up my other file.

So how can I get the functions from the first code block executed within the callback handler function in jQuery's `.delegate()` function?

**Edit in Response**

I think it's a step in the right direction.  I had a feeling it had something to due with the nature of JS and not necessarily the logic.  It's why I hate Javascript sometimes.

The problem with this solution is it's passing a primitive to a generic builder function.  I need to store and return an executable function.  The few things I've tried have been unsuccessful.  Here's an example of the many things I tried:

```
var _station = function(events){
    var _funcs = {}
    var _selection = null;

    var create = function(f){
        return function(){ return f() }
    }
    for(var t in events){
        _funcs[t] = create(t, events[t])
    }
    console.log(_funcs)

    // delegate the events to the primary SVG node
    for(var type in events){
        $('#stations', Bart.Map.node).delegate('g', type, function(e){                
            _funcs[type](e)
            e.stopPropagation()
        })
    }
}
```

When I `log(_funcs[type])` it comes back as a function, but I can't execute it for the life of me.

This closure stuff kills me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but I assume your problem is that you are creating a closure in a loop. Please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and let us know whether this fixes it.

Comment: Yes, I think it's something to do with that, but I can't get the code adapted to my uses. I updated the original post to reflect.  Thanks Felix, gonna bookmark that one for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have the problem with generating a closure an a loop. You can pass `type` as event data:

```
var $target = $('#stations', Bart.Map.node); // capturing is a good idea

for(var type in events){
    $target.on(type, 'g', {type: type}, function(e){                
        _funcs[e.data.type](e);
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
}
```

Or you can iterate over `events` with `jQuery.each`:

```
$.each(events, function(type) {
    $target.on(type, 'g', function(e){                
        _funcs[type](e);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

The important point is that every closure (event handler) has access to it's own `type` variable.

Note that I used `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`, as preferred since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: You beat me to it!  I revisited the `on()` method and it seems to work great.  Thank you very much for putting in the time.  Cheers!

Comment: @FelixKling, Do you know a way to delegate event on SVG elements?